# Partition a graph by vertex label

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I am working on a problem that requires to partition a directed labeled graph into several subgraphs. In each of the subgraph, the nodes are connected and they have the same label. Is there an efficient algorithm to solve this?

Comment: Define "partition". Sounds to me like running a simple DFS could solve your problem.

Comment: A set of vertices which are connected and have the label go into one partition

Comment: So you basically want to detect the graph components? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29?wprov=sfla1

Comment: yes, I come up with a solution and I will post it here

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution implemented in Java, it uses JGraphT as the graph library.

```
private Set<Set<Node>> partition(DirectedGraph<Node, Edge> graph) {
    Map<Node, Set<Node>> map = new HashMap<Node, Set<Node>>();
    for (Edge edge : graph.edgeSet()) {
        Node source = graph.getEdgeSource(edge);
        Node target = graph.getEdgeTarget(edge);
        if (source.getLabel().equals(target.getLabel())) {
            if (map.get(source) != null && map.get(target) == null) {
                map.get(source).add(target);
                map.put(target, map.get(source));
            } else if (map.get(target) != null && map.get(source) == null) {
                map.get(target).add(source);
                map.put(source, map.get(target));
            } else if (map.get(source) == null && map.get(target) == null) {
                Set<Node> set = new HashSet<Node>();
                set.add(source);
                set.add(target);
                map.put(source, set);
                map.put(target, set);
            } else {
                Set<Node> sourceSet = map.get(source);
                Set<Node> targetSet = map.get(target);
                sourceSet.addAll(targetSet);
                for(Node n : targetSet){
                    map.put(n,sourceSet);
                }
                targetSet = null;
            }
        } else {
            if (map.get(source) == null) {
                Set<Node> set = new HashSet<Node>();
                set.add(source);
                map.put(source, set);
            }
            if (map.get(target) == null) {
                Set<Node> set = new HashSet<Node>();
                set.add(target);
                map.put(target, set);
            }
        }
        Collection<Set<Node>> values = map.values();
    }
    return new HashSet<Set<Node>>(map.values());
}
```